# why the year "2007" can not be displayed in my generated pdf after compiling "http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Curriculum_Vitae"?

Tags: context, cv

I want to use the resume template [m-resume.tex and cv-resume.tex](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Curriculum_Vitae#cv-resume.tex), and downloaded it, combined the two files into one file called `resume.tex`, and then used `conTeXt mkiv`'s command context to compile it and generate a pdf smoothly, all content is ok, but there is no `year` such as `2007` in pdf like the original pdf: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/images/c/ca/Cv-resume.pdf.
[image]

What should I do for enabling it to display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not combine the two files, just save them as they are: `m-resume.tex` and `cv-resume.tex`

Then, run `texexec cv-resume.tex`. You will get your PDF without errors.

[image]

Comment: @@AboAmmar, When compiling `cv-resume.tex` I use command `texexec` and get a correct result. But in my own `cv.tex`, I used several modules from http://modules.contextgarden.net/, such as `Simplefonts`, I can compile successfully using `context cv`, but when I use `texexec cv.tex` I get a error `module simplefonts not found`