# conTeXt: What should I do for compile a tex file when I have two different types of modules?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, context-mkii

For resolving [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253638/81323) , according to [AboAmmar's answer] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253658/81323), I must create a separate file `m-resume.tex` and use command `texexec cv.tex` to compile it.

But in my cv.tex, I placed the file `m-resume.tex` at the same directory as `cv.tex` and also installed several modules from http://modules.contextgarden.net in the directory `texmf-local/tex/context/third/`, such as Simplefonts, I could compile successfully using `context cv` before, but when I use texexec cv.tex I get a error:

```
 module simplefonts not found
```

And When I use `context cv` I also get a error about `m-module.tex`.
So, what should I do for using such two different types of modules?

Comment: Did you
`mktexlsr`
and
`mtxrun --generate`
?

Comment: @AkiraKakuto, After downloading modules from  http://modules.contextgarden.net I installed it using `luatools --generate`, I did't use `mktexlsr and mtxrun --generate`, they are for what? Thanks!

Comment: `mktexlsr` updates the filename databases which allow TeX to find files in TEXMFMAIN and TEXMFLOCAL. Since you installed modules into TEXMFLOCAL, you need to run it so TeX can find them. If you install into TEXMFHOME, this is not necessary as that directory is searched directly (not using a database). `mtxrun --help | grep generate | grep -v auto` gives me `mtxrun          | --generate             generate file database`.